flutter_local_notifications zonedSchedule notification not firing on emulator
I am using Flutter flutter_local_notifications package in an app targeting Android.
I've set up the example app and am running it in Android emulator (API33).
When I use Show plain notification with payload it works, but when I click Schedule notification to appear in 5 seconds, nothing! The notification does not appear. There is no error either.
I've changed the androidScheduleMode to use "inexact" mode so I don't need additional permissions:
 Future<void> _zonedScheduleNotification() async {
    final nowDttm =
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    print('Scheduled: $nowDttm');

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        'scheduled title',
        'scheduled body',
        nowDttm,
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'your channel id', 'your channel name',
                channelDescription: 'your channel description')),
        androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.inexactAllowWhileIdle, //changed from exact
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }


The notification that does work is using this method:
  Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id++, 'plain title', 'plain body', notificationDetails,
        payload: 'item x');
  }

App has notification permission as shown by the other type of notification working.
Other's had problems with timezones but this is initialized correctly like so:
tz.initializeTimeZones();
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));

My AndroidManifest.xml is below (as requested):
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application
        android:label="notifications"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
  
</manifest>


Full project is on GitHub.
What am I missing here? How do I troubleshoot?

Inside your AndroidNotificationDetails, when you schedule a notification, make sure to add the importance and priority. You did it for your showNotification, but not when you schedule one.

thanks, but that does not help. Still not working! This is not my code btw, it is the example code for the project.

Did you add all the necessary permissions and providers in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

I think so. If I didn't, the other notification type wouldn't work either, isn't it?
This is what I have added to the manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


Please edit your question and add your AndroidManifest.xml file

added full manifest

Full project is here: https://github.com/under3415/notifications_sample

As mentioned in my comment, you did not follow the integration guide.
Part of it, besides adding the permissions and changing things in Gradle, is also to add receivers in your AndroidManifest.xml file so scheduled notifications work.
From the guide:

To schedule notifications the following changes are needed Specify the
appropriate permissions between the  tags. : this is
required so the plugin can known when the device is rebooted. This is
required so that the plugin can reschedule notifications upon a reboot
If the app requires scheduling notifications with exact timings (aka
exact alarms), there are two options since Android 14 brought about
behavioural changes (see here for more details) specify
 and call the
requestExactAlarmsPermission() exposed by the
AndroidFlutterNotificationsPlugin class so that the user can grant the
permission via the app or specify . Users will not
be prompted to grant permission, however as per the official Android
documentation on the USE_EXACT_ALARM permission (refer to here and
here), this requires the app to target Android 13 (API level 33) or
higher and could be subject to approval and auditing by the app
store(s) used to publish theapp Specify the following between the
 tags so that the plugin can actually show the scheduled
notification(s)

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file and scheduled notifications should work:
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

